# kendo datasource filter with three conditions

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I want to filter my kendo datasource by three conditions, it has to meet them all

but when I run this line of code I get undefined is not a function

```js
viewModel.savedRepairTypesDataSource.filter(
  {logic:"and", filters: [
    {field:"item",operator:"eq",value:item},  
    {field:"category",operator:"eq",value:category},
    {field:"estimateId",operator:"eq",value:estimateId}
  ] 
});
```

Comment: Can you put togther a jsfiddle or plunkr with this?  The code above works for me with dummy data.

Comment: ya do a jsfiddle or post your code with the Json result

Comment: I was able to get this to work, not sure what was going on thanks guys